# Convert SQLITE 'NoneType in a int python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to "SELECT" a value from Db and add this value to another variable, but when I execute this I get this error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int' "

```
id = input("Digite o id do cartão: ")
cash = int(input("Digite o o valor a ser creditado: "))
dia = 3
sql = 'SELECT saldo FROM carteira where idcartao = ?'


def selectbanco():
     c.execute("SELECT saldo FROM carteira WHERE idcartao=?", (id,))
     row = c.fetchone()
     print(row)
     row = c.fetchone()
     soma = (row) + (cash)
     c.execute("UPDATE carteira SET saldo=?  WHERE idcartao=?", (soma, id))
     connection.commit()
selectbanco()
```

THIS IS MY COMPLETE CODE

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('clientes.db')
c = connection.cursor()
#criação de tabela
def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carteira (idcartao REAL, saldo REAL, data text)')
create_table()
#variaveis
id = input("Digite o id do cartão: ")
cash = int(input("Digite o o valor a ser creditado: "))
dia = 3
sql = 'SELECT saldo FROM carteira where idcartao = ?'

#SELECT E RETORNAR VALOR
def selectbanco():
    c.execute("SELECT saldo FROM carteira WHERE idcartao=?", (id,))
    row = c.fetchone()
    print(row)
    row = c.fetchone()
    ##soma = (row + cash)
    ##print(soma)
    c.execute("UPDATE carteira SET saldo=?  WHERE idcartao=?", (cash, id))
    connection.commit()

selectbanco()

#leitura do banco
def read_data(wordUsed):
    for row in c.execute(sql, (wordUsed,)):
        print (row)
read_data(id)

connection.close()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch *two* rows?

Comment: Remove the second `row = c.fetchone()` line.

Comment: Well, not just that, but `fetchone()` will return `None` if you don't get a single match, even if you were just calling it once.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two issues here.

The first is that you exhaust your generator by calling `row = c.fetchone()` twice, without re-executing the query. You can only iterate through your cursor once for each query result; after that, you will need to re-run the query to "refresh" the data and be able to iterate again.

Second, `fetchone()` will actually return `None` if you get no matches. This is in contrast to `fetchall()` that will instead return an empty list (`[]`) in the case of no matches.

This quick example should illustrate this behaviour:

```
import sqlite3

# Create a fake database
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table(
                something TEXT
            )""")

c.execute(""" INSERT INTO some_table VALUES('hello') """)


c.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")
# We get a match and this will print '(hello,)'
data = c.fetchone()
print(data)


data = c.fetchone()
# If we don't execute the query again but try to use the exhausted generator
# then we'll also get None
print(data)


c.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE something = 'bye'")
# This will print 'None' because fetchone() didn't get a result
data = c.fetchone()
print(data)


c.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE something = 'bye'")
# This will print an empty list because fetchall() didn't get a result
data = c.fetchall()
print(data)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Even though `None` and `[]` are different, they are still *falsey* so, in the context of your question, you can still convert either response to an integer:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""create table if not exists some_table(
                something TEXT
            )""")

c.execute(""" INSERT INTO some_table VALUES('hello') """)

# Get back None or an integer
c.execute(""" SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE something = ?""", ('bye', ))
data = c.fetchone() or 1 # This is where you return an integer instead of None
print(data)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

I've picked an integer value of `1`, maybe you want `0`, I'm not sure. The thing to note, though, is that there's two avenues for you to get `None` or falsey data here, and you're treating them both the same, which isn't great for clarity of code.

Comment: what I am wanting to do is basically a database system where I take a database value and add a value of a variable that is a new credit

As a prepaid card system that adds up the previous amount with the new credit

Comment: @TiagoPessoa I'm pretty sure my answer covers all bases on why your current approach doesn't work....

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to python and I did not understand the problem

Comment: @TiagoPessoa that's fine, but I'm unsure what extra information you are asking me for in relation to your problem.

Comment: I've post my complete code, can you show me how to get a number in the SELECT in "saldo" and add to "cash" variable?

Comment: @TiagoPessoa That's beyond the scope of your initial question.

Comment: ok, now i'm receving the row, but when i try to add the value (int) of the cash variable  with the value that i get of the db in row variable  i get this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Comment: @TiagoPessoa you need to take the 0th index of whatever result is returned (add to `result[0]`). SQL will always return tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching row twice. You need to remove the second fetch to receive the row.

```
def selectbanco():
     c.execute("SELECT saldo FROM carteira WHERE idcartao=?", (id,))
     row = c.fetchone()
     print(row)
     soma = (row) + (cash)
     c.execute("UPDATE carteira SET saldo=?  WHERE idcartao=?", (soma, id))
     connection.commit()
selectbanco()
```

The variable gets overwritten because you do not specify a command to execute before fetching (the second time), hence the NoneType.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to get `NoneType` returned even if they executed the query only once. `fetchone()` will return `None` in the case of no matches, rather than an empty container like `fetchall()`

Comment: This is true! But with the code provided the duplicate fetch is causing the NoneType. If it keeps appearing after the removal of the duplicate than this would be the case.